# Why is sbt using incorrect version number for declared dependencies?

Tags: scala, sbt, scala-macro-paradise

I have a sbt build file that use 1 plugin and 3 dependencies:

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

val reflect = Def.setting { "org.scala-lang" % "scala-reflect" % "2.10.4" }

val compiler = Def.setting { "org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % "2.10.4" }

lazy val macrosSettings = Project.defaultSettings ++ Seq(
addCompilerPlugin("org.scala-lang.plugins" % "macro-paradise_2.10.4-SNAPSHOT" % "2.0.0-SNAPSHOT"),
libraryDependencies ++= {
  import Dependencies._
  Seq(play_json, specs2, reflect.value)
}
)

lazy val Macros = Project(id="IScala-Macros", base=file("macros"), settings=macrosSettings)
```

However the compiler gave me the following error in compiling IScala-Macros:

```
[warn]  :: org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.10.4-SNAPSHOT: not found
[warn]  :: org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.4-SNAPSHOT: not found
[warn]  :: org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.10.4-SNAPSHOT: not found
```

this seems like a bug as I don't want them to resolve to 2.10.4-SNAPSHOT, but only 2.10.4, is it a bug of sbt? If not, where does this SNAPSHOT come from?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues in this `build.sbt` build definition so I highly recommend reading the document [Macro Paradise](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/paradise.html) where you can find [the link to a project](https://github.com/scalamacros/sbt-example-paradise) that *for an end-to-end example, but in a nutshell working with macro paradise is as easy as adding the following two lines to your build (granted you’ve already set up SBT to use macros).*

As to the issues in this build, I don't see a reason for `Def.setting` for the depdendencies `reflect` and `compiler`, and moreover I'm unsure about the dependency in `addCompilerPlugin`. Use the one below where `Def.setting` is used to refer to the value of the `scalaVersion` setting. I still think `addCompilerPlugin` should follow the sample project above.

```
import Dependencies._

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

val reflect = Def.setting {
  "org.scala-lang" % "scala-reflect" % scalaVersion.value
}

val compiler = Def.setting {
  "org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % scalaVersion.value
}

lazy val macrosSettings = Project.defaultSettings ++ Seq(
  addCompilerPlugin("org.scala-lang.plugins" % "macro-paradise_2.10.4-SNAPSHOT" % "2.0.0-SNAPSHOT"),
  libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    play_json,
    specs2,
    reflect.value
  )
)

lazy val Macros = Project(id="IScala-Macros", base=file("macros"), settings=macrosSettings)
```

Comment: Sorry the original build file is very long and convoluted: I modify from this:
https://github.com/mattpap/IScala/blob/master/project/Build.scala
Namely I change scalaVersion from 2.10.2 to 2.10.4

Comment: Let me fork a new git project on this to show you the complete file

Comment: OK I have forked a new branch: https://github.com/tribbloid/IScala/blob/master/project/Build.scala

Comment: The problem become latent as I switched macro-paradise to a newer artifact, however it's reason is still unknown to me. I later switched to maven from sbt due to some jar hell issue, as sbt has very scarce plugin to handle it

Comment: What Maven plugin did you use to resolve *"the jar hell issue"*? Would you mind updating my answer to complete it as per your solution? I'd appreciate. If you accepted it afterwards, I wouldn't mind :)